# Difference between "font-family" and font-family?

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-family

I just discovered that my Chrome will treat `font-family: "sans-serif"` and `font-family: sans-serif` differently (it will choose different fonts). Can anyone explain how this works?  <s>I can't find any clues in the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-family-prop).</s> [edit: ...as I obviously didn't read them very carefully.]

Comment: `"san-serif"` is treated a string, whereas `sans-serif` is going to get to the dash and freak out.

Comment: In quotes it stands for a specific font whereas the unquoted sans-serif stands for the generic-family (other examples would `serif`, `cursive`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the same [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-family-prop):

> If a sequence of identifiers is given as a font family name, the
>   computed value is the name converted to a string by joining all the
>   identifiers in the sequence by single spaces.
>
> **To avoid mistakes in escaping, it is recommended to quote font family names that contain white space, digits, or punctuation
>   characters other than hyphens:**

So when you are writing "san-serif" then it is a specific font and is considered as a string whereas the latter is considered as generic.

Comment: Thank you! I should add that I found the `"sans-serif"`-declaration in a number of emails that all seem to be sent from Microsoft Outlook.

Comment: The most relevant part of the spec is really the sentence “Generic font family names are keywords and must NOT be quoted.”

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela:- Yes I agree and I think OP must have read that by now carefully +1 ;)

Comment: In practice, declaring `font-family: "sans-serif"` has no effect, since there is no font with that name. The font used depends thus on other CSS rules or ultimately browser settings and browser defaults.